# Вычислить контрольную сумму строки

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте я хочу вычислить контрольную сумму строки например `std::string name = "victor";` в гугле я нашел реализации на алгоритмах crc, md5 а так-же множество разных вариантов, но все они использовались для файлов или таблиц, а как лучше будет вычислить контрольную сумму для строк?

Comment: Они просто для *данных*, неважно каких. Так что берите и используйте то, что вам нравится. Вряд ли вам нужно что-то особо сложное...

Answer (score 1):

В C++11 в стандартную библиотеку добавили алгоритмы расчета hash, с помощью которой вы можете рассчитывать контрольную сумму:

```
// hash example
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string str1 ("Test");
    std::string str2 ("Test");
    
    std::hash<std::string> str_hash;
    
    std::cout << "same hashes:\n" << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "str1 and str2: " << (str_hash(str1)==str_hash(str2)) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::hash` - только hash, предназначенный для отображения данных в некий короткий целочисленный индекс, который потом может использоваться для поиска в различных контейнерах, а не стойкая "контрольная сумма" в смысле криптографического sha256, sha512 и т.д., коллизии которых маловероятны, и по совпадению таких hash можно судить об идентичности данных. Коллизии же для `std::hash` встречаются постоянно. Основное требование - лишь равномерное распределение по "корзинкам" контейнера. Автору всё же требуется выбрать требуемый тип криптографического hash и применить соответсвующую библиотеку.